# OneLogin for Java: configure certificate and PK

Tags: java, saml, onelogin

How do I configure certificate and PK exactly ?

For security I probably don't want to keep my PK in my source code. So how do I specify a custom path ?

But in the meantime is this correct ?

```
# Usually x509cert and privateKey of the SP are provided by files placed at
# the certs folder. But we can also provide them with the following parameters
onelogin.saml2.sp.x509cert = -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIICQjCCAaugAwIBAgIEJC7VoDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBUMQswCQYDVQQGEwJV
...
rYsMZmOthlq9nzyvTgYPWUozUX2PsUvrWDOehtulcfO9GbT7TqhSfs96RWoAJlpx
DVnF33gs
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

# Requires Format PKCS#8   BEGIN PRIVATE KEY         
# If you have     PKCS#1   BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY  convert it by   openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform pem -nocrypt -in sp.rsa_key -outform pem -out sp.pem
onelogin.saml2.sp.privatekey = -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIICdgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAmAwggJcAgEAAoGBAKUKJ+2aDsroFdbv
...ZKL4hvtee3nRwXyjjVdeXF9vZrbqSAkVdRt+RnqtqvvHTkpUWWoHWhNT8ijyLvst
+L8dfnvBv2S6hg==
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Related to this: what is the difference between using a certificate vs using a certificate fingerprint ?

Thank you,
Simon

Answer (score 1):

Currently the java-saml only is able to read SP public cert/private key from the settings file. Support read them from files is something that we want to implement [Issue 54](https://github.com/onelogin/java-saml/issues/54) and [Issue 55](https://github.com/onelogin/java-saml/issues/55) but can't say to you when it gonna be ready.

Properties on settings MUST be in 1 unique line so your values are wrong.

fingerprint is an easier way to provide a way to validate the signatures of the SAMLResponse when it is sent using HTTP-POST binding (not valid on SAML Messages sent using HTTP-Redirect binding).